# Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation for explanation

Tags: captions, subfig

I have used these packages in my Springer format, but I am getting above warning. Although warning can be ignored but, without removal of this warning, I am not unable to upload or build PDF on that particular journal website.
The warning is about [caption package](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/float/caption.pdf), and I have not used it in my project. By adding this package also, I am getting the same error.

Kindly help how me to remove this warning.

My document contains, text, figures, subfigures references only.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%

%
% \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
%\usepackage{latexsym}
% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}


\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{array}
% \usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{footnote}
% \usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{ mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage{subfig}

\sloppy
```

Comment: you *are* loading the caption package. Remove it. If you want to sent something to a journal which provides a class, avoid to clutter your preamble with lots of packages which perhaps change the layout they want.

Comment: I have removed it, but still nothing changed

Comment: then remove more stuff. Or check in the log which package is issuing the warning.

Comment: `subfig` (which you load twice) and `subcaption` are not compatible. Remove one of it.

Comment: I have removed subfig and caption package and now it is working fine.

Comment: You also rethink, if you really need all those packages in your preamble. You need to move `hyperref` on the end of preamble and if you will use `cleveref` than it had to be after `hyperref` package

Comment: ok, thanks a lot

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Comment: clashing of packages can be interesting for posterity. I say keep open and accept the (short, yet important) answer.

Comment: Oh, missed the fact that the answer came a year later... My bad

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Zarko for making my day to solve this problem :

I have removed
`\usepackage{caption}  %subfigure`
and
`\usepackage{subcaption}  %subfigure`, then it worked fine.